# axios + query-string vs. jQuery, POST data broken by query-string

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios, query-string

#### data example we want to send by ajax

```js
const dataExample = {
    "userId": '...id',
    "supportFormId": 14,
    "supportFormName": 'Tickets',
    "customFields": [
        {
            "customFieldId": 80,
            "name": 'Subject',
            "value": '...',
            "dataType": 'Text'
        },
        // ....
        {
            "customFieldId": 84,
            "name": 'Description',
            "value": '...',
            "dataType": 'Text'
        }
    ]
}
```

#### jQuery ajax call

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://....',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataExample,
    success: function (data) { /* ... */ }
});
```

#### axios + query-string ajax call

```js
import axios from "axios";
import qs from 'query-string'

const dataQs = qs.stringify(dataExample);

return new Promise(
    async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                data: dataQs,
                url: 'http://....'
            });
            if (response) return resolve(response)
            return reject()
        } catch (err) { return reject(err) }
    }
);
```

#### result

[image: result]

#### question

***jQuery* never has any type of problem** but *axios + query-string*, despite different headers like

```js
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
```

and/or
optional stringify options like

```js
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { encode: false })
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { arrayFormat: 'indices', commaSuffix: 'bracket' })
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { arrayFormat: 'indices' })
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' })
const dataQs = qs.stringify(data, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })
```

breaks the data all the times..

**which is the correct axios + query-string (or alternative) code to get the same result of jQuery?**

Comment: You send json formatted data with jQuery and url/parameter (query-string) encoded data with axios. As you use query-string, it is always url-encoded with axios; no matter what header (content-Type) you use. Perhaps the server can only handle json data, so it works with jQuery and fails with axios. Have you access to and looked into the server logs? You could format the data string with `JSON.stringify` and use `Content-Type: application/json` to try. Just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like below

```js
const objectToQueryString = (initialObj) => {
    const reducer = (obj, parentPrefix = null) => (prev, key) => {
      const val = obj[key];
      key = encodeURIComponent(key);
      const prefix = parentPrefix ? `${parentPrefix}[${key}]` : key;

      if (val == null || typeof val === 'function') {
        prev.push(`${prefix}=`);
        return prev;
      }

      if (['number', 'boolean', 'string'].includes(typeof val)) {
        prev.push(`${prefix}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`);
        return prev;
      }

      prev.push(Object.keys(val).reduce(reducer(val, prefix), []).join('&'));
      return prev;
    };

    return Object.keys(initialObj).reduce(reducer(initialObj), []).join('&');
  };

  objectToQueryString({
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 20,
    children: [
      { name: 'Foo Doe' },
      { name: 'Bar Doe' }
    ],
    wife: {
      name: 'Jane Doe'
    }
  });
  // -> name=John%20Doe&age=20&children[0][name]=Foo%20Doe&children[1][name]=Bar%20Doe&wife[name]=Jane%20Doe
```

Taken from below gist

https://gist.github.com/tjmehta/9204891

Comment: this is the solution I was looking for!!! thank you very much, it works!!! you will get 50+ in 23 hours :)